# Visual Studio Application Insights toolbar not showing events

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I'm new to Application Insights and testing the concept of sending custom data in a console application. I managed to see custom events in the search bar in the Azure portal, great.

My problem is in some of the tutorials I went through, there's a toolbar in Visual Studio that shows the number of events e.g. **Application Insights (21)** but mine just has **Application Insights** without a number next to it and clicking on it shows 0 events

My code is uber-simple:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_GUID";

    TelemetryClient TC = new TelemetryClient();
    TC.TrackEvent("My event");
    TC.Flush();
}
```

I'm got Visual Studio 2015. Should I install something to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to add the `ApplicationInsights.config` file to your project.

Make sure Build Action is `Content` and Output Directory is `Copy if newer` / `Copy always` so that it copies file to output directory on build

[image]

Also, make sure you at least have the `<ApplicationInsights ...` root tag in your config file. Something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
    </ApplicationInsights>
```

Comment: Just curious, why Build action should be set to content?

Comment: You need the config file to be in the output directory for this to work.